# How to bind primary key of a selected value from listBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using listBox to show results of a searched value. I want that after searching a value,  user will select a value from searched results, its Id that is PK(Primaray Key) should pass to selected results instead of that selected item. [image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaiK0.png For example in attached image I want that when user will click on "assignment7" its id value i.e **8** should pass to selected result field. How can i do it. Need your guidance. Thank You!

Here my code is:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="PrintText" Background="DarkGray" Visibility="Collapsed"  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,36,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
  <Grid>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" x:Name="textBlock1"  Text="For Search Type here" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="auto" Width="auto" Foreground="White" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,12,0,246" x:Name="textBox1" Width="191" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
        <ListBox Foreground="White" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="PrintText" Background="DarkGray" Visibility="Collapsed"  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,36,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="389,0,0,248" x:Name="txtSelectedItem" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="91" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </Grid>

  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

  string typedstring= textBox1.Text;
List<string> autolist= new List<string>();
foreach(string b in al)
{
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
if(b.StartsWith(typedstring))
{
autolist.Add(b);
}
}
}
if(autolist.Count>0)
{
    listBox1.ItemsSource = autolist;
    listBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

}
else if (textBox1.Text.Equals (""))
{

    listBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    listBox1.ItemsSource = null;
}

else
{

    listBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    listBox1.ItemsSource = null;
}


        }

        private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
             selectedItemsId = (int)listBox1.SelectedValue;
            if (listBox1.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                listBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                textBox1.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
            }

            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                textBox1.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
            }
        }
        void PrintText(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {


             Window1 neww = null;
             neww = new Window1();
             neww.Title = selectedItemsId.ToString();
             neww.Show();
        }



        private void SetupListBox()
        {
            List<Assignment> lst = new List<Assignment>();


            listBox1.ItemsSource = lst;
            //This is what will be displayed
            listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "assignment_title";
            //This is what will set the selected value to the property you want
            listBox1.SelectedValuePath = "assignment_id";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set selected value path to the PK field and then use selected value to get the current value

```
 class Example
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private void SetupListBox()
    {
        List<Example> lst = new List<Example>();
        lst.Add(new Example { id = 1, Name = "First Item" });
        lst.Add(new Example { id = 2, Name = "Second Item" });
        lst.Add(new Example { id = 3, Name = "Third Item" });

        listBox1.ItemsSource = lst;
        //This is what will be displayed
        listBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        //This is what will set the selected value to the property you want
        listBox1.SelectedValuePath = "id";
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the selected Items id property
        int selectedItemsId = (int)listBox1.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: how to Set selected value path to the PK field?

Comment: the listbox will have a selectedValuePath property that takes a string.  Just give it the name of the property that is your PK

Comment: jfin3204 SelectedValuePath="{Binding assignment_id}" ... like this?

Comment: @TameenMalik either way there is no need to use binding.  Just use the name of the property, the binding syntax is used for setting the itemssource once that is set you just need to give it the name of the property ie SelectedValuePath="assignment_id"

Comment: jfin3204,  in code. actually i am new to c# that's why i am confused. sorry to disturb you :)

Comment: @TameenMalik No problem that is what the site is for give me a minute and I'll update the post with some code.

Comment: Thank you friend! but there is a problem that it is assigning 0 value to selectedItemsId.

Comment: @TameenMalik I need to see more of your code. Specifically where you are setting all of the things I added to the code  in the answer, i do not see  selectedItemsId in the code you posted.

Comment: You are setting the listboxes itemssource in multiple places.  I am assuming that al is a collection of Assignment objects,correct? One problem  is that in the textBox1_TextChanged method you are creating a list of strings and assigning that to the listboxes items source, at this point you will no longer be able to use selected value because a string doe not have an assignment_id property, if al is a list of assignments that you need to select a subset of then  autolist needs to be  a list<Assignment>  not List<string>

Comment: i am initializing it in MainWindow() method! ... now what  i have to do. Please guide me . thank you!

Comment: @TameenMalik what is al? It looks like it is a list<string>.  It needs to be a List<Assignment>, string does not have an assignment_id property, so it is impossible for the listbox to access the assignment_id property for selected value.

Comment: Actually it is a string array which is used to search entered value in a search bar by using for loop. When user will enter any value in search box, this for-loop will find it and will display it in listBox1.

Comment: If you look at the code i posted.  The list box has  an itemssource set equal to a list<Example> objects.  Since the Example class has an id property i set the SelectedValuePath = "id".  If i change the itemssource to a string[] then i can no longer access selectedvalue because string does not have an id property. Does this make sense?

Comment: ok i get it. dear friend, so now as i want that whenever i enter any value in textbox to search it, then its result should display in listbox1. and when i will click on any item present in this listbox, then its primary key should display. so can i do this by following code provided by you?

Comment: If I understand your question, then yes. if al is list<Assignment> and you do something like b.assignment_title.StartsWith(typedstring) and then add b to the autolist then when a user selects the item in the listbox selectedvalue should have your key